# how can i change the colors of title boxes in amcharts

Tags: amcharts

I have changed my chart colors but the title boxes are not changed. How can I change them

[POLAR SCATTER CHARTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK1iL.png)

Comment: Please provide your code in a jsfiddle or codepen that reproduces your problem. This makes it easier for folks to help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: @xorspark https://jsfiddle.net/0vqxwfoa/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legend markers ignore `bulletColor` by default. You have two options to change the marker color:

1) Set [`lineColor`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#lineColor) to change your legend marker and bullet colors instead of using `bulletColor`.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ..
  "graphs": [{
    "lineColor": "#000088",
     // ... omitted ..
   },
   // ... etc
   ],
   // ...
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/d5195464f2f8168324491093c7ac9765?editors=0010)

2) If you rather use `bulletColor`, you can set [`useGraphSettings`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#useGraphSettings) to true in your legend, which makes your legend use your `bulletColor` but changes your markers to bullets instead of boxes.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "legend": {
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    // ...
  },
  // rest stays the same
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/bcbf766606b710f50e50152edf1c9969?editors=0010)